# losing resolution when using FME Webmaptiler

Tags: fme-form

I'm new to using FME and could use some help. I'm trying to take a Geotif image and tile it up into pngs using webmaptiler.

The issue I'm having is that the png tiles look pretty poor in quality/resolution when compared to the original Geotif quality.

It appears that I am generating data in perhaps 8bit or something?

I have a maintenance/support agreement with Safe, and I've submitted several support requests, and have yet to hear back from them. Hopefully this is something pretty simple that some of the experts here can assist me with.

[image: FME WebMapTiler]

[image: FME WebMapTiler Properties]

[image: FME Reporjector Properties]

Comment: Did you get an automated email back from the support team with a case number? If so I can use it to chase up a response.